# Freeze when shutting down Ubuntu 18.04 without Internet connection

Tags: shutdown, freeze, acer

I am a newbie to Linux, and I installed Ubuntu 18.04 recently on my Acer Aspire VX laptop.

But sometimes, when I try to shut down my computer, the mouse disappears, and everything freezes until I press the power off button.
Although, I have noticed that this happens only, and always, when I am offline. 
I have tried to add

```
acpi=force
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

in `/etc/default/grub`, but that doesn't work, and I don't find anything about that happening only when being offline.